# Timing issues with the GPS

Tags: android, gps

This is a problem that is quite the opposite of the "regular" use of the GPS. The goal is to have the gps read or "fix" at a very precise rate (when available) across the multitude of devices that exists. So until now I believed that the timing parameter in e.g.

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1f, this);
```

would take care of this for me. But behold, when testing on a Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus I got completely different behavior, almost opposite (minimum time between reads in one case, maximum in the other). Why is this, and what could be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this

If you read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), you will see that the `minTime` parameter to `requestLocationUpdates()` "is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value".

> what could be done to fix it?

You come up with a new design that makes no assumptions whatsoever about the availability and frequency of GPS fixes.

Comment: Yes, I remember reading something like that as well. Thing is that the timings have never really been an issue until now. I guess programmatically requiring a minimum amount of time would take care of most of the issues, but it isn't exactly at a given rate. I'm also quite aware of the issues with blocked signals etc, so at the moment I'm considering an ideal case. Any idea of where to get information about maximum timings under ideal conditions?

Comment: @Scalar: "Any idea of where to get information about maximum timings under ideal conditions?" -- beats me. That would be dependent on too many hardware-specific variables IMHO (e.g., chipset). The best you are going to be able to do is specify a `minTime` of `0`, process every fix that comes in, smooth out the data rate yourself, and pray for no parking garages. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid to get that answer ;-) Thanks Though!